# warning :format 'c' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'char '

Tags: c, format, warnings

I'm new on stack overflow and I need some help, excuse me but I don't understand where is the problem, someone can help me?

I have the message:

> warning: format 'c' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has
> type 'char '

and I don't know how to resolve it.

Code:

```
typedef struct Ajouter_un_joueur Joueurdef;
struct Ajouter_un_joueur {
    char nom_joueur[30];
    char prenom_joueur[20];
    unsigned int numero_joueur;
    char personnage[50];
};

int main() {
    Joueurdef joueur;
    
    printf("Choisir le nom de votre joueur \n");
    
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c", joueur.nom_joueur);
    
    printf("Choisir le prenom de votre joueur \n");
    
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c", joueur.prenom_joueur);
    
    printf("Choisir un numero unique pour votre joueur \n");
    
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%u", &joueur.numero_joueur);
    
    printf("Choisir le nom de votre personnage\n");
    
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c", joueur.personnage);
    
    printf("Vous etes %c %c, votre numero est le %u et votre personnage est %c", 
           joueur.prenom_joueur, joueur.nom_joueur, joueur.numero_joueur,
           joueur.personnage);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `fflush(stdin);` is not a proper way to get rid of pending input. It actually has undefined behavior.
- `%c` in a `scanf()` conversion specification expects to read a single character, not a string. If the input for `nom`, `prenom` and `personnage` are single words, you can use `%s` instead of `%c`. If white space is allowed, use `%[^\n]` to read characters until the end of line. An initial space in the format string will skip the pending newline and an initial whitespace.
- to output a string in `printf`, use `%s` instead of `%c`. The error message is a bit misleading and probably has a star `*` at the end: `warning: format 'c' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'char *'`

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Ajouter_un_joueur Joueurdef;
struct Ajouter_un_joueur {
    char nom_joueur[30];
    char prenom_joueur[20];
    unsigned int numero_joueur;
    char personnage[50];
};

int main() {
    Joueurdef joueur = { 0 };
    
    printf("Choisir le nom de votre joueur \n");
    scanf(" %29[^\n]", joueur.nom_joueur);
    
    printf("Choisir le prenom de votre joueur \n");
    scanf(" %19[^\n]", joueur.prenom_joueur);
    
    printf("Choisir un numero unique pour votre joueur \n");
    scanf("%u", &joueur.numero_joueur);
    
    printf("Choisir le nom de votre personnage\n");
    scanf(" %49[^\n]", joueur.personnage);
    
    printf("Vous etes %s %s, votre numero est le %u et votre personnage est %s\n", 
           joueur.prenom_joueur, joueur.nom_joueur, joueur.numero_joueur,
           joueur.personnage);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, the program work good now :)